# Upstox auth API throwing error in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use upstox API for authorization and login. More details here [[https://upstox.com/developer/api-documentation/#tag/Authentication]](https://upstox.com/developer/api-documentation/#tag/Authentication)

I have the MainActivity that has only Login button and its listener.

```
package com.apps.upstoxtrade;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String AUTH_URL = "https://api-v2.upstox.com/login/authorization/dialog";
    private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/redirect";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call the login functionality
                performLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void performLogin() {
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Handle URL loading within the WebView itself
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                // Check if the URL contains the authorization callback URL
                if (url.startsWith(AUTH_URL)) {
                    // Extract the code parameter from the URL
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");

                    // Use the code to get the access token
                    getAccessToken(code);

                    // Return true to indicate that the URL has been handled
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        AUTH_URL = AUTH_URL+"?response_type="+RESPONSE_TYPE+"&client_id="+CLIENT_ID
                +"&redirect_uri="+REDIRECT_URI;

        webView.loadUrl(AUTH_URL);
    }

    private void getAccessToken(String code) {
        // You can use any networking library of your choice to make an HTTP request to fetch the access token.
        // Here, I'm using a simple synchronous HTTP request for demonstration purposes.

        // Replace this with the actual HTTP request code using your preferred networking library.
        String accessToken = fetchAccessToken(code);

        // Handle the access token as needed (e.g., store it, use it for further API requests, etc.).
        if (accessToken != null) {
            // Access token obtained, do something with it
            Toast.makeText(this,accessToken,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            // Access token retrieval failed
        }
    }

    // Replace this method with your actual HTTP request code to fetch the access token
    private String fetchAccessToken(String code) {
        // Replace this with the actual code to fetch the access token using the "code" parameter.
        // You can use libraries like Retrofit, OkHttp, etc., to make the HTTP request.
        // For this example, I'm simply returning a hardcoded access token for demonstration purposes.

        // Example response: {"access_token":"your_access_token","expires_in":3600,"scope":"read"}
        return "your_access_token";
    }
}
```

But on click of login app throws an error.

[image]

This **UDAPI100016** error comes due to redirect error, I have resolved this error in webapp, but not sure why it is again coming up in android. Is my redirect proper?

Comment: Can you please tell how did you fixed on webapp ?? Im indeed need this

Answer (score 0):

Please add `/` at the end of the redirect URL.
Change `http://localhost:3000/redirect` to `http://localhost:3000/redirect/`

Answer (score 0):

Redirect URI should be the same as you provided in your app in upstox, that should solve your problem, and maybe try '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' in your redirect uri

Answer (score 0):

In latest API version (V2) upstox uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication and login and in OAuth 2.0 upstox does not support localhost URls.

Insted of your localhost url try using web based url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).